# Regular expression to not match an apostrophe

Tags: c#, regex

I can have either of the below two sentences in a word document:
Issuer\r\aDC Issuer\r\a or

Issuer’s Guarantor\r\aDuetche bank(Moody’s Q6)

I want to get the value whatever is present after Issuer.
The regex I wrote to match the first line is 
^(Issuer)(.*?(?=[A-Z0-9]))(\w+(\s*\w+)*).

But the problem is sometimes the file will have **Issuer's Guarantor** instead of Issuer and it matches ***Issuer's*** as well, even though I want to match  **Issuer** specifically.
So Is there any way I can say with a Regular expression not to match Issuer's and match the only Issuer?

Could not add the screenshot for regex match as I am still new and the tool won't allows me. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Negative lookahead.

Comment: Try to read a lot of tutorials before asking.

Comment: Also... is the regex an **image**? Or is it **text**? Why do you want to post an image?

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply.Negative lookahead does seem to do the trick. I modified the expression to ^(Issuer)(?!’)(.*?(?=[A-Z0-9]))(\w+(\s*\w+)*), It's now matching the Issuer's now. Yeah.. you are right. I need to read a lot about regex.

Comment: Edit into the question please.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't match now, is that what you want? No? The question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant its now matching

Comment: Couldnt you just do .Replace("Issuer's", "") ?

Comment: Try [`Regex.Matches(s, @"(?m)^Issuer(?![’']s)\s*(.*)$").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eIssuer%28%3f!%5b%e2%80%99%27%5ds%29%5cs*%28.*%29%24&i=Issuer%0d%0aDC+Issuer%0d%0a+or%0d%0a%0d%0aIssuer%e2%80%99s+Guarantor%0d%0aDuetche+bank%28Moody%e2%80%99s+Q6%29&o=m).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *negative lookahead*:

`^Issuer(?!'s)(.*)$`

The regex will now discard any `Issuer` followed by a `'s`, and the remaining text is captured.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/enuT4W/1)